# "node run dev" can't work ,how to fix it?

Tags: npm, solidity, npm-scripts, smartcontracts, truffle

I want to run "truffle serve" which linked to localhost:8080.
[But get this error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVDmd.png)

Then I tried to find the problem which may be the version of truffle.
I tried "npm run dev". But failed with [this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbWLJ.png).

How can I solve the problem?, please help me.

Comment: `dev` in this scenario is the name of a property in the `scripts` object of your `package.json`. Obviously this property has not been defined.

Comment: I must add dev scripts in my dapp/package.json ?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include actual code and the actual error message instead of images -- http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the `scripts`section in your `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
   "dev": "truffle serve",
   // other scripts that may already be defined here
}
```

This allows you to execute `truffle serve` by issueing `npm run dev`.

Regarding your `fsevents is not a constructor` problem, please refer to

> https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/463

which suggests that issueing

> `truffle init webpack`

solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the command `npm run serve`